# Build an iOS 8 App with Bluemix and the MobileFirst Platform for iOS

Tags: ios, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I followed [Link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-mfp-ios8-app/) to achieve iOS App with Bluemix. I followed all the steps which are given in upper link.

I am getting error "Error creating remote data store Error Domain=Unify Code=100 "Failed to create remote database."

For reference please find below logs -

```
2016-06-15 15:05:53.913 bluelist-objective-c[665:177849] Intializing IMFCLient
2016-06-15 15:05:53.914 bluelist-objective-c[665:177849] IapplicationRoute http://bluemixiosapp.mybluemix.net
2016-06-15 15:05:53.914 bluelist-objective-c[665:177849] IapplicationId 3168ea0e-10b5-4b12-8ae5-1c6d980996bc
2016-06-15 15:06:06.724 bluelist-objective-c[665:177849] 

IMFDataManager initialized successfully:
CloudantToolkit Version: 1.1.1
CloudantToolkit Build Date: 20150911_0800
IMFData-Bluemix Version: 1.1.1
IMFData-Bluemix Build Date: 20150911_0800
Target URL: https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/imfdata/api/v1/apps/3168ea0e-10b5-4b12-8ae5-1c6d980996bc



2016-06-15 15:06:07.101 bluelist-objective-c[665:177849] Local data store created successfully
2016-06-15 15:06:08.390 bluelist-objective-c[665:177890] [ERROR] [BlueList] Error creating remote data store Error Domain=Unify Code=100 "Failed to create remote database.
HTTP_Status: 404
JSON Body: (null)" UserInfo=0x178078200 {NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to create remote database.
HTTP_Status: 404
JSON Body: (null)}
```

I cant able to find from where this error coming. Expecting help to sort out my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error because [IMFData](https://cocoapods.org/pods/IMFData), a key dependency of the no longer supported [imf-bluelist](https://hub.jazz.net/project/mobilecloud/imf-bluelist/overview) sample, has been deprecated and decommissioned.

Unfortunately, you will not be able to get this sample to work in it's current state.

I recommend trying out the [iOS samples](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=iOS) located in our [Bluemix mobile services GitHub](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services), specifically [helloTodo](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-ios-hellotodo).

You can also take a look at [CDTDatastore](https://cocoapods.org/pods/CDTDatastore) and [Cloudant NoSQL DB](https://bluemix.net/catalog/services/cloudant-nosql-db/) if you're looking for persistent data storage.